# how I can use back-reference in boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am tring to use back-reference in boost version 1.44 but this don't work for me.
this is my code:

```
 boost::regex_constants::syntax_option_type flags = boost::regex::extended;
 std::string regx="(aaa)bb\1";
 std::cout << "Expression:  \"" << regx << "\"\n";
 std::string str ="aaabbaaa";
 boost::regex e(regx,flags);
 if(boost::regex_match(text, what, e))//, boost::match_extra))
 {
   std::cout<<"found";
 } else
 {
   std::cout<<"not found";
 }
```

and this is my ouput:

```
   Expression:  "(aaa)bbb☺"
   ** not found **
   Press any key to continue . . .
```

what I am missing?
when I try `std::string regx="(aaa)bb\\1"` program crashed in `boost::regex e(regx,flags);`
mybe I miss some flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem by chaning this row

```
   boost::regex_constants::syntax_option_type flags = boost::regex::extended;
```

to

```
   boost::regex_constants::syntax_option_type flags = boost::regex::bk_vbar;
```

and ofcourse use `\\`
and this work for me.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`"(aaa)bb\\1"`. You need to escape the backslash.

Comment: what is body? and I try `\\1`  but crashed in boost::regex e(regx,flags);

Comment: @herzl, I ment use `\\1` instead of `\1`, not as a whole separate regex.

Answer (score 1):

Both C++ and the regex use `\` as an escape character. When you use it in your string C++ is interpreting it as octal character constant 1. You'll need to double escape the 1: `std::string regx="(aaa)bb\\1";`

Comment: but when I try  \\1 it is crashed in boost::regex e(regx,flags);

Answer (score 1):

In addition to needing to escape your backslash:

Boost::regex sets the extended-syntax specific no_bk_refs flag by default. If you want to use back-references with extended syntax you'll have to unset it yourself:

```
flags = boost::regex::extended  & ~boost::regex::no_bk_refs;
```